# jsf Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null in join table

Tags: jsf

i got an error on my datatable "Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null", it caused by one column with join with another table, normally i initiate everything in my beans, this is my code, someone can enlighten me please ?

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class locationBean extends LazyDataModel<Location> {

private Location selectedLocation;
private List<Location> locations;
private List<SelectItem> selectoneitemclient;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
    this.selectoneitemclient = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    this.selectedLocation = new Location();
}

public List<SelectItem> getSelectoneitemclient() {
    ClientDao clientdao = new ClientDaoImpl();
    List<Client> clients = clientdao.selectItems();
    for (Client cl : clients) {
        SelectItem selectitem = new SelectItem(cl.getCodecl(), cl.getNom());
        this.selectoneitemclient.add(selectitem);
    }
    return selectoneitemclient;
}

public List<Location> getLocations() {
    LocationDao locationdao = new LocationDaoImpl();
    this.locations = locationdao.findAll();
    return locations;
}
```

location.xhtml

```
<h:form id="formDataTable">
                <p:dataTable var="location" value="#{locationBean.locations}" rowKey="#{location.codeloc}" paginatorPosition="bottom" paginator="true" rows="10"
                             paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" selectionMode="single" selection="#{locationBean.selectedLocation}" id="tableLocation">
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{locationBean.onRowSelect}" update=":formDisplay" oncomplete="PF('dialogLocationDisplay').show()" />
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Listes des réservations
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:column headerText="Type client" filterBy="#{location.client.typecl}" 
                              footerText="contains"
                              filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{location.client.typecl}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Nom" filterBy="#{location.client.nom}" 
                              footerText="contains"
                              filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{location.client.nom}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Tel" filterBy="#{location.client.tel}" 
                              footerText="contains"
                              filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{location.client.tel}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Email" filterBy="#{location.client.email}" 
                              footerText="contains"
                              filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{location.client.email}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Date Debut" filterBy="#{location.datedebut}" 
                              footerText="contains"
                              filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{location.datedebut}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Date Fin" filterBy="#{location.datefin}" 
                              footerText="contains"
                              filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{location.datefin}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Gestion">
                        <p:commandButton id="btnUpdate" update=":formUpdate" oncomplete="PF('dialogLocationUpdate').show()" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="modifier">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{location}" target="#{locationBean.selectedLocation}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton id="btnDelete" update=":formDelete" oncomplete="PF('dialogLocationDelete').show()" icon="ui-icon-trash" title="supprimer">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{location}" target="#{locationBean.selectedLocation}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
            <h:form id="formUpdate">
                <p:dialog header="modifier une reservation" widgetVar="dialogLocationUpdate" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
                    <p:outputPanel id="detailLocationUpdate" style="text-align:center;">
                        <p:panelGrid  columns="2" columnClasses="label,value">
                            <h:outputText value="Client: " />
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{locationBean.selectedLocation.client.codecl}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="- Selectionner un client -" itemValue = "" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{locationBean.selectoneitemclient}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>

                            <h:outputText value="Titre: " />
                            <p:inputText value="#{locationBean.selectedLocation.titre}" />
```

LocationDaoImpl.java

```
@Override
public List<Location> findAll() {
    List<Location> listloc = null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    String sql = "FROM Location l inner join fetch l.client";
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        listloc = session.createQuery(sql).list();
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listloc;
}

@Override
public boolean update(Location loc) {
    boolean flag;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Location locdb = (Location) session.load(Location.class, loc.getCodeloc());
        locdb.setCodeloc(loc.getCodeloc());
        locdb.setTitre(loc.getTitre());
        locdb.setClient(loc.getClient());
        locdb.setDatedebut(loc.getDatedebut());
        locdb.setDatefin(loc.getDatefin());
        locdb.setTotalttc(loc.getTotalttc());
        session.update(locdb);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        flag = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        flag = false;
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Please add Complete StackTrace. When exception is coming ? Page rendered time or updating any value from the List.

Comment: Exception handling is bad. If anything fails in your DAO, you're continuing the code as if nothing exceptional happened. Replace `e.printStackTrace();` by `throw e;`, rerun the code and reframe your question to focus on that exception. Also learn to pay more love and attention to server logs.

Comment: it's okey thanks to you i fixed